# Can I save a list in Memcache in Google-AppEngine in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I want to save a list in MemCache in AppEngine with Python and I am having the next error :

TypeError: **new**() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given).

This is the link of the image with the error : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/we3VU.png

And this is my code :

```
def get_r_post_relation(self, url, update = False) :
        sufix = "r"
        key = sufix + url
        list_version = memcache.get(key)
        if not list_version or update :
            logging.error("LIST VERSION QUERY")
            postobj = get_wiki_post(url)
            list_version = WikiPostVersion.query().filter(WikiPostVersion.r_post == postobj.key)
            memcache.set(key, list_version)
        return list_version
```

Comment: Why did you link to a screenshot of that error, rather than posting the text here?

Comment: This is the error : TypeError: new() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given).

Comment: Which is line 27?

Comment: What - @Lajos Arpad?

Comment: This is the line 27.  list_version = memcache.get(key).  @Lajos Arpad

Comment: Jean, that seems to be the starting point. It does some calls under the hood which result in an instantiation where a constructor is called with a single parameter, while the constructor expects four parameters.

Comment: What kind of items in that list?

Comment: it contains a list of entities of the google datastore

Comment: I know that @LajosArpad but the get parameter of the Memcache only get one parameter.

Comment: Jean, that is true, but something under the hood calls a constructor with a parameter while there is a constructor with four parameters. Take a look at the lines shown at the stack trace and find the new() invoked with a single parameter. It seems to be done by reflection. If so, you can debug it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not storing a list.  You are storing a query object.  To store a list, use `.fetch()`:

```
list_version = WikiPostVersion.query().filter(WikiPostVersion.r_post == postobj.key).fetch()
```

You can store a simple query object, but when you add `.order()` or `.filter()`, you'll get a pickling error.  Change to list, and you're all set.

Remember, a query object doesn't have any entities in it.  It is simply a set of instructions that will go and retrieve the entities when used later with a `.get()` or `.fetch()`.  So, you are trying to store a python command set, when your intention is to store the actual entity list.

Comment: It works!, Thanks very much, you save me of my Headache :-) @GAEfan. 5 Stars for you XD.